# Orthogonal vectorspace properties

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality

I got *V* as an euclidean space, *U* $\subset$ *V* as subspace and *v* $\in$ *V*$\setminus$*U*.
I want to show that there exists exactly one *u* $\in$ *U* so that *(v-u)* $\in$ *U$^{\bot}$*.

*U$^{\bot}$* is the vector space which includes every vector *x* that has the property $\langle$*x*,*u*$\rangle$= $0$ , with *u* $\in$ *U*.

In my case there is $\langle$*(v-u)*,*u*$\rangle$= $0$. That's the same as $\langle$*v*,*u*$\rangle$$-$$\langle$*u*,*u*$\rangle$= $0$ and $\langle$*v*,*u*$\rangle$=$\langle$*u*,*u*$\rangle$

But *v* can't be *u* and *u* can't be *v*, because of *v* $\in$ *V*$\setminus$*U* and *u* $\in$ *U*.

How can I find the "fitting" *u* for each *v*?

Of course *u* = *$0$$_v$* is not the answer I am searching.

Comment: Not always true. If $U$ is a proper subspace and $v$ is orthogonal to $U$ then there are infinitely many such vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $U$. The desired $u \in U$ is equal to $Pv$.

Indeed $v = Pv + (v - Pv)$ and $v - Pv \perp U$:

$$\langle v - Pv, x\rangle = \langle v, x\rangle - \langle Pv, x\rangle = \langle v, x\rangle - \langle v, Px\rangle = \langle v, x\rangle - \langle v, x\rangle = 0, \forall x \in U$$

To show uniqueness, assume that $v = a + a' = b + b'$ where $a,b \in U$, and  $a', b' \in U^\perp$.

Then we have

$$\underbrace{a - b}_{\in U} = \underbrace{b' - a'}_{\in U^\perp}$$

so $a - b = 0$ and $b' - a'=  0$.

---

Without assuming that we know that $P^T = P$, we can proceed like this: let $\{e_1, \ldots, e_k\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $U$ and let $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ be its extension to an orthonormal basis for $V$. Then the projection $P$ is given by $$Px = \sum_{i=1}^k \langle x, e_i\rangle e_i$$

Now it is clear that $$v - Pv = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v, e_i\rangle e_i 
- \sum_{i=1}^k \langle v, e_i\rangle e_i = \sum_{i=k+1}^n\langle v, e_{i}\rangle e_i \in U^\perp$$
because $e_j \perp U$ for all $k+1 \le j \le n$.

Comment: Took me a few minutes. Thanks for the effort

Comment: How does it come that you turn ⟨Pv,x⟩ into ⟨v,Px⟩? Shouldn't it become into ⟨v,P$^{T}$x⟩ ?
How do you know that P is symmetric ?

Comment: @IPiiro Orthogonal projections are always symmetric. Verify that $$\langle P(x+x'), y+y'\rangle = \langle Px,y\rangle = \langle x, Py\rangle = \langle x+x', P(y+y')\rangle$$
if $x,y \in U$ and $x', y' \in U^\perp$.

Comment: @IPiiro Actually, I added a different approach which does not assume that $P = P^T$ is already known.